# self-made addon cannot be used in other computer (Windows 10 & 11)

Tags: python, interface, add-on, windows

Is there anyone else experience the same on other modules or vanilla when installing their customized addon?

I'm stuck in this for a long time. I have created an addon that includes other modules (GDAL) and installed it via pip in Blender. This worked fine on a few devices, but others malfunctioned. The phenomenon is, after installing the addon, there is no error or warning message, but the button doesn't show as planned.

I tried many devices which were all 64 bit WIN10/WIN11. The version of Blender was 3.4.1. I had already put `INSTALLED_PATH\Blender\3.4\python\bin` into the system variable *path*. This addon used GDAL 3.4.3, which was installed with *GDAL-3.4.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64* from uci official site.

Here is the code:

````
bl_info = {
    "name": "Mesh Convert",
    "author": "ABC",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Sidebar > Convert tab ",
    "description": "Convert GeoReferenced Mesh",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Geography",
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector

import bmesh
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr
import winreg

def get_ref_loc( x_ave, y_ave, *args, **kwargs):
    input_epsg = 2436 ## Beijing 1954 / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger CM 117 E
    output_epsg = 4326 ## WGS 1984


    # create a geometry from coordinates
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)


    # create coordinate transformation
    inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(input_epsg)

    outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(output_epsg)

    coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)
    point.AddPoint(y_ave, x_ave)

    # transform point
    point.Transform(coordTransform) 
    
    return point

def output_txt( point, output_path, *args, **kwargs):
    
    #   output txt file
    temp_arr = [ str(point.GetX()), str( point.GetY() ) ]
    temp_arr = list(map(str, temp_arr))
    temp_arr = ",".join(temp_arr)
    print(temp_arr)

    attr_file = output_path + "\\geometry.txt"
    with open(attr_file, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8', newline = "") as file:
        file.write( temp_arr + '\n')
        del file

def output_fbx( temp_filepath, *args, **kwargs):
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx( 
        filepath = temp_filepath, 
        check_existing=True, 
        filter_glob='*.fbx',
        # use_active_collection=True,
        use_selection=True, 
        object_types={'MESH'},
        path_mode='AUTO',
        bake_anim=False,
        bake_space_transform=False,
        global_scale=1.0,
        apply_unit_scale=True,
        apply_scale_options='FBX_SCALE_NONE',
        use_space_transform=True,
        axis_forward='-Z',
        axis_up='Y',
        mesh_smooth_type='OFF',
        colors_type='SRGB',
        use_mesh_modifiers=True,
        add_leaf_bones=True,
        primary_bone_axis='Y',
        secondary_bone_axis='X',
        armature_nodetype='NULL',
        batch_mode='OFF')
    
def get_desktop():
  key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders')
  return winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "Desktop")[0]

def main_fk():
    # Get the active mesh
    me = bpy.context.object.data


    # Get a BMesh representation
    bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMeshS
    bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh


    # get original coordinance
    temp_x_arr = []
    temp_y_arr = []

    # Modify the BMesh, can do anything here...
    for v in bm.verts:

        temp_x_arr.append(v.co.x)
        temp_y_arr.append(v.co.y)
        # create a geometry from coordinates
        print(v.co)


    x_ave = sum(temp_x_arr) / len(temp_x_arr)
    y_ave = sum(temp_y_arr) / len(temp_y_arr)



    # Move terrain
    for v in bm.verts:
        v.co.x = v.co.x - x_ave
        v.co.y = v.co.y - y_ave

    bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm)

    # get refefence location
    point = get_ref_loc( x_ave, y_ave)

    # set output path to desktop
    cwd_1 = get_desktop()

    # output txt file
    output_txt( point , cwd_1)
    # cwd_1 = get_desktop()
    temp_src = "A.fbx"
    temp_filepath = cwd_1 + "\\" + temp_src
    # temp_filepath = ""



    # Finish up, write the bmesh back to the mesh
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    bm.free()  # free and prevent further access
    output_fbx( temp_filepath)

class simple_operator(Operator):
    """Convert WuShan Mesh"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Obejct Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        # print( context.object)
        main_fk()
        return {'FINISHED'}


class OBJECT_CONVERT_panel_1(bpy.types.Panel):
    
    bl_idname = "mesh.convert_object"
    bl_label = "Process FBX"
    # bl_label = "Panel 1"
    bl_category = "Convert tab"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    # bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        layout.label(text="Click Here")

        col = layout.column(align=True)
        # row = col.row(align=True)
        # row.prop( obj, "show_name", toggle=True, icon="FILE_FONT")
        col.operator( simple_operator.bl_idname, text="Convert SRS", icon="CONSOLE")
        # layout.box()
        # main_fk()

        # return {'FINISHED'}


classes = [
    OBJECT_CONVERT_panel_1,
    simple_operator]

def register():
    # bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    # bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Uninstall the addon completely. Then Go to the menu Window > Toggle console, and install the addon again. Hopefully the system console should show what is happening.

Comment: @L0Lock Thank your for your idea! I tried but didn't work. I found the reason afterwards. The reason is that I set this button to be view only when there is one mesh existed. Anyway, thank you very much.